# How to Debug a Node.js file using Visual Studio Code?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code 1.79.2, and I am trying to Debug a Node.js file, which is named Index-multiclient.js, which is acting as a WebSocket Server.

I cannot figure out what I need to do to run it in Debug Mode.

My version of VS Code does not seem to match the Tutorials I found on YouTube.
My Launch.json file looks as follows:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "launch Program",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
        }
    ]
}
```

If I go to RUN AND DEBUG, I am presented with "launch Program", and I don't know what to hit next.

Answer (score 0):

Your launch config is missing the `"program"` property where you pass the path to the script file you want to run with NodeJS. Ex.

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "launch Program",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "multiclient.js" // <- added this line
        }
    ]
}
```

If you want to read more about debugging NodeJS apps in VS Code, see the official docs at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging.

Answer (score 0):

If the file you want to debug is the current editor, then it is simpler to use the `${file}` variable in your launch configuration like so:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "launch Program",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Node: Run current file",
            "program": "${file}"
        }
    ]
}
```

And then look for `Node: Run current file` in the Launch Configurations dropdown box.

Comment: Hi Mark, Can you explain why you have "name" in there twice?  When I tried this, I got an error of duplicate Object key. Thanks!

Comment: Oops, just a typo.  Use only one - whatever descriptive name you want.